# Authenticate against AD after ssh into Windows Server

Tags: ssh, active-directory, ssh-keys

Apparently after **ssh into a Windows Server with a key-file** the (domain) user is logged into the machine - but not authenticated against the AD Active Directory.

So when when log4j tries to write a log-file to a network share it is unable to write the file..
I tried to fix this by a `net use` command but this works only some-times.

**Any ideas how to authenticate against the AD after a (domain) user is successfully logged into a Windows Server??**

Comment: How exactly did you determine that the user is NOT being authenticated by the domain server?

Comment: On [this site](https://sc1.checkpoint.com/documents/R81/SmartEndpoint_OLH/EN/Topics-EPSG/Active-Directory-Authentication.htm) it says that authentication logs are in `%DADIR%/logs`. You must be getting some sort of authentication error. Can you add to your question, what you're trying to do, when you get that error? And also please add the full error as well.

Comment: @Ramhound the problem was a permission denied (or similar message) after so intense research I found in the internet that ssh from linux with keyfiles makes the user beeing able to log-in but the user is not authenticated against the AD. So accessing network resources does not work.

Comment: @Zeth I'm not an admin of AD .. an if I understand right there is no request against the AD since the user does not log-in with the AD-Password but with a key-file..

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there were 2 issues:

- For `net use` to map a network drive (e.g. drive X) the drive must not exists already.. so I made sure to unmap it first by `net use x: /delete`
- 2nd in one case of `net use x: UNC User Password` the domain was missing before the user .. it needs to be there in the format `domain\user`